# SQL forcing me to use default value and property

Tags: mysql, sql

Strange trouble indeed!

I am experiencing this issue when (My)SQL add some properties to my table, that I don´t want to be there and that I can´t change, even if I run right command and get "SUCCESS" reply.

Here is code for creating such a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `KIIS_EVENT_APPLICATION`
             (
                  `ID_USER` smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
                  `ID_EVENT` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
                  `COMES` timestamp,
                  `LEAVES` timestamp,
                  `TRANSPORT_THERE` varchar(30) COLLATE cp1250_czech_cs,
                  `TRANSPORT_BACK` varchar(30) COLLATE cp1250_czech_cs,
                  `ROLE` varchar(30) COLLATE cp1250_czech_cs NOT NULL,
                  `RELEVANCE` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
                  FOREIGN KEY (`ID_EVENT`) REFERENCES `KIIS_EVENTS`(`ID_EVENT`),
                  FOREIGN KEY (`ID_USER`) REFERENCES `KIIS_USERS`(`ID_USER`)
                 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1250 COLLATE cp1250_czech_cs
```

Let´s see the result:
[image]
Yellow highlighted things I don´t asked for.

If I run query, such as

```
ALTER TABLE  `KIIS_EVENT_APPLICATION` CHANGE  `COMES`  `COMES` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL;
```

page says, it is successfully done, but nothing changes.

**How can i make COMES column to be same as LEAVES column ?**

---

Could it be caused by missing primary key? Do I need one when I have 2 foreign there (is it good SQL design practice, or?) ?

Comment: If you can reproduce the issue, report the bug to phpmyadmin team.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE  KIIS_EVENT_APPLICATION MODIFY COLUMN COMES TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00';` or more correctly, `... TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL`.

Comment: The first timestamp column in a table gets magical behavior by default prior to MySQL Server 5.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Michael - sqlbot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695906/michael-sqlbot) got it right in comment.

> `ALTER TABLE KIIS_EVENT_APPLICATION MODIFY COLUMN COMES TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'`; or more correctly, ... `TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL`
>
> The first timestamp column in a table gets magical behavior by default prior to MySQL Server 5.6.

I added

```
timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

properties to all columns with such a behaviour and it works just fine.

Great!